# What's qsort void*x and *(int*)x?

Tags: c++

can someone please explain the work of

1. `*(int*)x;`
2. `const void *x`
3. `qsort(mass, 2*c, sizeof(int), sort)`
4. `return i>0 ?i:(-1.0*i)`

in this code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long

int sortt(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    int e=*(int*)x;
    int e1=*(int*)y;
    if(e>e1)
       return 1;
    else
       return -1;
}

double abss(double i)
{
    return i>0 ?i:(-1.0*i);
}


int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n,m,i,t=1,sum;
    while(scanf("%d %d",&n,&m)==2)
    {
        double avg=0,balance=0;
        int a[15];
        sum=0;
        for(i=0; i<15; i++)
            a[i]=00000000;
        for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
            sum+=a[i];
        }
        avg=(double)sum/n;
        for(i=m; i<2*n; i++)
        {
            a[i]=0;
        }

        qsort(a,2*n,sizeof(int),sortt);
        printf("Set #%d\n",t++);
        int first,last;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            first=a[i];
            last=a[2*n-i-1];
            if(first==0 && last !=0)
            {
                printf(" %d: %d\n",i,last);
            }
            else if(first==0 && last==0)
            {
                printf(" %d:\n",i);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" %d: %d %d\n",i,first,last);
            }
            balance+=abss(((double)first+(double)last)-avg);
        }
        printf("IMBALANCE = %0.5lf\n\n",balance);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Its a UVA OJ problem(410) Solve
what is the difference between this sorting style and cpp built in sort function
read about qsort in cpprefernce but didnt understand much :(

Comment: Suggested reading material: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort.

Comment: Don't include<bits/stdc++.h>. Use std::sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qsort` has the following prototype:

```
void qsort(
  void *base,
  size_t nel,
  size_t width,
  int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)
)
```

`base` is a pointer to the memory region to be sorted (`a`). `nel` is the number of elements (`2 * c`), and `width` is the size of each element (`sizeof (int)`). `compar` is a pointer to a function which should accept two pointers to elements in the region, and return whether the first is less than (`-1`), equal to (`0`), or greater than (`1`) the second.

`qsort` uses `void` pointers because it’s designed to operate on any type. So in the comparator function, you must *cast* the `const void*` pointers you receive to the appropriate type. `*(int*)x` simply means “convert `x` from a `const void *` into an `int *`, and dereference it to obtain an `int`”.

The comparator accepts `const void *` pointers because it’s not supposed to modify the contents of the array being sorted. Therefore `*(const int *)x` would be slightly better in style, since it preserves `const`-ness.

Finally, `return i > 0 ? i : -1.0 * i` uses the conditional operator `?:` which is semantically the same as `if` but in the form of an expression rather than a statement; it simply means:

```
if (i > 0)
  return i;
else
  return -1.0 * i;
```

The difference between `qsort` in C and `std::sort` in C++ is that the C++ sort retains static type information, improving safety, and can be *specialised* by the compiler to a particular type and comparator, improving performance by avoiding an indirect function call.

Comment: thanks but the basic behind *(int*)x is still unclear..need to study more about pointers :)

Comment: but what is difference when I use 'sort' instaed of 'qsort'
wont they give back the same value?

Comment: The other big difference is that `std::sort` works with non-POD types, while using `qsort` on these types is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ToufiqueImamNuhash: They both sort the elements, but they may use different algorithms. `qsort` is a QuickSort, while `std::sort` may choose one of several different algorithms, for example, based on the type of iterator or size of container. In general, if you’re writing in C++, you should always prefer `std::sort` for improved safety and performance. As @PaulMcKenzie mentions, `qsort` only works for “plain old data” (POD) types, basically those that can be safely copied byte-for-byte with `memcpy`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but if i use the "sort" function here to sort lower to upper result varries..dont know why

Comment: @ToufiqueImamNuhash Then you are using `std::sort` incorrectly.  Using `std::sort` to sort integers is one line of code without any casts, comparison functions, or any other thing you used for `qsort`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `qsort` is capable of sorting arbitrary data types (e.g. `int`, `double`, custom data types introduced by `struct`, ...). As it does not know the data types and their sizes, it requires - besides the array of elements and the number of elements therein - two additional things: (1) the size of one element, necessary when the algorithm needs to swap two elements, and (2) a comparison function that decides for two elements `x` and `y` whether `x>y`, `x<y`, or `x==y`. As `qsort` can work with any data type, the signature of the comparison function takes `x` and `y` as data type `void*`.

If your array contains integers, then you pass `sizeof(int)`. The comparison function needs to compare integers, yet they are passed as pointers to void, i.e. `void* x`; so you have to cast it back to pointers to int, i.e. `(int*)x` and then to dereference it to get the value (not the pointer), i.e. `*(int*)x`.
Hope it helps.

Note that in C++ `qsort` is limited to objects of [trivial type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf):

> 25.5 C library functions
>
> qsort: ... The behavior is undefined unless the objects in the array
>   pointed to by base are of trivial type.

Comment: `qsort` will *not* work with any data type when it comes to C++.  If the type is non-POD, using `qsort` on a sequence of these types is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: thanks for the valuable note; Some detail: Does it have to be POD? `qsort` refers to `trivial type`, which is less restrictive than POD, isn't it?

Comment: I guess if `std::is_trivial<T>` returns `true` for type `T`, then it can be used in a call to `qsort`.  But I wouldn't tempt fate and instead always use `std::sort`.  There is no advantage at all in using `qsort` in a C++ program.